# Django: Redirect if the link doesn't match urlpatterns

Tags: django, redirect, url-pattern

How do I make django to redirect from www.example.com to www.example.com/home ?

Below you can see my urlpaterns and I'm using `url(r'', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='home', permanent=False))`to redirect to my /home page but when it detects a link without / at the end it redirects me to the /home page.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/', views.home, name="home"),
    url(r'^surukkam/$',views.shrink,name="surukkam"),
    url(r'^(?P<inputURL>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)/$',views.retrieve,name="virivu"),
    url(r'', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='home', permanent=False))
]
```

Comment: Try with `r'.*'` since `r''` would only match an empty string.

Comment: @solarc no, that is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is redirecting because you missed `^$` at the end of home URL.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/$', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/$', views.home, name="home"),
    url(r'^surukkam/$',views.shrink,name="surukkam"),
    url(r'^(?P<inputURL>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)/$',views.retrieve,name="virivu"),
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='home', permanent=False))
]
```

`^$` - it is a regular expression that specifies the start and end points of a URL string.

whenever your Django detects the empty string it will direct to this URL.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: sorry if I ask but is a way to make that to redirect to sh.mysite instead of www.mysite? Also, I removed the home so I have just sh.example.tk ^^

Comment: I cant understand can you elaborate.what is `sh`?